# Tagged Template Literals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, template-literals

Dipping a toe into JavaScript. After C, C++ and Python, JavaScript is like wild west. Can someone explain why do I get the output that doesn't make any sense:

```js
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function foo(strings, ...values) {
    let a = values[0];
    let b = values[1];

    return `Sum ${a + b} Product ${a * b}  Division ${b / a}`;
}

console.log(foo`Num1 ${a + 10} Num2 ${b * 2}  Num3 ${b / a}`);
```

**The output:**  *Sum 35 Product 300  Division 1.3333333333333333*

Comment: Which part specifically doesn't make sense? You're doing a lot of different things here; it might be valuable to reduce the scope of each "thing". Like `values[0]` is coming in as `15`, `values[1]` will be `20`, so the sum is `35`, which seems correct.

Comment: What did you expect to get?

Comment: "After C, C++ and Python, JavaScript" if you had just said C++ and Python I would have understood the comparison, but C is about as "wild west" as it gets short of assembler.

Comment: Please refer to the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates), it should explain your output and the proper usage perfectly.

Comment: @Dave you are right.  This is a sample code from a course, so I missed the fact that we have passed different values to the function already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values presented to you in the function are the following:

```js
let strings = ['Num1 ', ' Num2 ', '  Num3 ', ''];
let values = [15, 20, 2]; // a+10, b*2, b/a
```

You are returning:

```js
`Sum ${15 + 20} Product ${15 * 20}  Division ${15 / 20}`
```

This is expected as it evalulated the templates and then ran them inside the tag as well.

Comment: This is it! That's what I have missed!

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates):

> Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function. The first argument of a tag function contains an
> array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions.
>
> The tag function can then perform whatever operations on these arguments you wish, and return the
> manipulated string.

It might seem to be an unusual construct, but your code demonstrates how it works.
The `strings` argument is an array `['Num1 ', 'Num2 ',  'Num3 ', '']`, which are the literals before, between, and after the expressions, and the `values` are the evaluated expressions `[15, 20, 2]`.